# Rename a single column in kable() table

Tags: r, knitr, kable

All -

I feel like I'm overlooking a simple solution. Is there a way to rename a single column in a kable() table?

Example of the original table.

`library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
tbl <- tibble(first_point=c(1,2,3), Second=c(4,5,6), Third=c(7,8,9)) 
kable()`

[image: Table1]

Example of the desired table. I would prefer to not have to specify the "Second" and "Third" column names.

`kable(tbl, col.names=c("First","Second","Third")`

[image: Table2]

EDIT:

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions. I used @bouncyball's simple but effective tactic of automatically adding the column names for the other columns rather than manually including them when changing a single column. I didn't even consider that route. `kable(tbl, col.names = c("First", names(tbl)[-1]))`

Comment: Why not rename the column first and then use it in `kable` ? `names(tbl)[1] <- 'First'`

Comment: I've considered that option but thought against it because I have numerous tables and I didn't want to add a bunch of new code, I'm creating a template in RMarkdown and wanted to keep it simple for folks, and I didn't want to modify column names to reduce possible confusion. Renaming may be the best option though.

Comment: Use this code to do a temporary rename of just one column:  `kable(local({names(tbl)[1] <- "First"; tbl}))`

Comment: `kable(tbl, col.names = c("First", names(tbl)[-1]))`

Comment: And of course you could write a more general function to do what the `local()` call did, e.g. `renameOne <- function(tbl, col = 1, newname = "First") { names(tbl)[col] <- newname; tbl }`